# Security field in swagger paths

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I've added a security field to an endpoint in swagger, but the swagger-ui (editor.swagger.io) renders this endpoint exactly the same as an endpoint without security description:

This is how I've added the security description:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
  securitySchemes:
    JWT:
      name: Authorization
      in: header
      type: apiKey
      description: JWT token

security:
  - JWT: []

    get:
      security:
        - JWT: [ manager ]
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

In OpenAPI 3, you can define your `securitySchemes` as a component in the `components` section and then set the `security` at API top level or endpoint level.

See the following example

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Your API
  description: Your API description
  version: 0.0.1

# This sets all paths with authentication
security:
  - BearerAuth: []

paths:
  /users:
    post:
      summary: Create a new user
      operationId: createUser
      security: [] # <-- disable auth for a specific path
      tags:
        - Users
      requestBody:
        ...
      responses:
        ...

  # The security is inherited from API level
  /users/me:
    get:
      summary: Get user information
      operationId: getUser
      tags:
        - Users
      requestBody:
        ...
      responses:
        ...

components:
  # Security
  securitySchemes:
    BearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

Full reference for Authentication can be found [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) and for Bearer Auth (JWT) [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/)